Is there a better approach to decoding swaps from different DEXs?
I am trying to build a Telegram Bot where a user can track DEX Swaps that occur on particular wallets, on multiple chains.
I have noticed that different DEXs deal with Swaps differently, and, from what I've gathered, you have to decode the Logs of each Receipt (to get all the Transfers, Deposits, Swaps, etc) and, depending on the DEX, use a specific method of getting the exact correct In and Out tokens & amounts.
The Swap()s appear to show amount1 and amount2, but those values (particularly the amount that goes IN to the wallet at the end) are sometimes incorrect (due to fees I think). The value that goes IN to the wallet appears to be wrong, so that's why Transfers have to be used (looking at the order of transfers, the wallet address to see if it's on the from or to, etc).
I feel like there must be a more streamlined way to deal with this (simply getting the ACCURATE in and out and the tokens from a Receipt).
There are no APIs out there that I've seen that aggregate and decode all this simply. Moralis provide a Wallet History endpoint, but that gets ALL transactions for a wallet, instead of just 1, and is expensive.
I'm looking to do everything via RPC if possible, unless an API is very cheap to use.
I'm using Base for now, and NodeJS.
A receipt (TXID is: 0x72823453899fe671cdf0742f5dd3725d3f52e6f65660d31318e327969a850bcb) looks something like this (in my receipts.js file):
export const receiptThree = {
  "receipt":{
     "blockHash":"0xbe2cadb0b88ae723bb2d87293f41c64f3242c12fe7e841f3ecc0698d6e3e9701",
     "blockNumber":"0x160cc3e",
     "contractAddress":null,
     "cumulativeGasUsed":"0x762315",
     "effectiveGasPrice":"0x2198a60",
     "from":"0xf4123c2a38d9aa57801a6469b415f8116208feab",
     "gasUsed":"0x3fd0b",
     "l1BaseFeeScalar":"0x8dd",
     "l1BlobBaseFee":"0x1f3e2b33d",
     "l1BlobBaseFeeScalar":"0x101c12",
     "l1Fee":"0x31abeaa5c88",
     "l1GasPrice":"0x1bf934a78",
     "l1GasUsed":"0x175f",
     "logs":[
        {
           "address":"0x000000000022d473030f116ddee9f6b43ac78ba3",
           "blockHash":"0xbe2cadb0b88ae723bb2d87293f41c64f3242c12fe7e841f3ecc0698d6e3e9701",
           "blockNumber":"0x160cc3e",
           "data":"0x000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006773824b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
           "logIndex":"0xc7",
           "removed":false,
           "topics":[
              "0xc6a377bfc4eb120024a8ac08eef205be16b817020812c73223e81d1bdb9708ec",
              "0x000000000000000000000000f4123c2a38d9aa57801a6469b415f8116208feab",
              "0x000000000000000000000000fde4c96c8593536e31f229ea8f37b2ada2699bb2",
              "0x0000000000000000000000003fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad"
           ],
           "transactionHash":"0x72823453899fe671cdf0742f5dd3725d3f52e6f65660d31318e327969a850bcb",
           "transactionIndex":"0x24"
        },
        {
           "address":"0x833589fcd6edb6e08f4c7c32d4f71b54bda02913",
           "blockHash":"0xbe2cadb0b88ae723bb2d87293f41c64f3242c12fe7e841f3ecc0698d6e3e9701",
           "blockNumber":"0x160cc3e",
           "data":"0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003d340",
           "logIndex":"0xc8",
           "removed":false,
           "topics":[
              "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef",
              "0x000000000000000000000000d56da2b74ba826f19015e6b7dd9dae1903e85da1",
              "0x0000000000000000000000003fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad"
           ],
           "transactionHash":"0x72823453899fe671cdf0742f5dd3725d3f52e6f65660d31318e327969a850bcb",
           "transactionIndex":"0x24"
        },
        {
           "address":"0xfde4c96c8593536e31f229ea8f37b2ada2699bb2",
           "blockHash":"0xbe2cadb0b88ae723bb2d87293f41c64f3242c12fe7e841f3ecc0698d6e3e9701",
           "blockNumber":"0x160cc3e",
           "data":"0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003d4b0",
           "logIndex":"0xc9",
           "removed":false,
           "topics":[
              "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef",
              "0x000000000000000000000000f4123c2a38d9aa57801a6469b415f8116208feab",
              "0x000000000000000000000000d56da2b74ba826f19015e6b7dd9dae1903e85da1"
           ],
           "transactionHash":"0x72823453899fe671cdf0742f5dd3725d3f52e6f65660d31318e327969a850bcb",
           "transactionIndex":"0x24"
        },
        {
           "address":"0xd56da2b74ba826f19015e6b7dd9dae1903e85da1",
           "blockHash":"0xbe2cadb0b88ae723bb2d87293f41c64f3242c12fe7e841f3ecc0698d6e3e9701",
           "blockNumber":"0x160cc3e",
           "data":"0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffc2cc0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003d4b00000000000000000000000000000000000000001002c925e1b662b91a39fa1b3000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000022b0e3a0afc4000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d",
           "logIndex":"0xca",
           "removed":false,
           "topics":[
              "0xc42079f94a6350d7e6235f29174924f928cc2ac818eb64fed8004e115fbcca67",
              "0x0000000000000000000000003fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad",
              "0x0000000000000000000000003fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad"
           ],
           "transactionHash":"0x72823453899fe671cdf0742f5dd3725d3f52e6f65660d31318e327969a850bcb",
           "transactionIndex":"0x24"
        },
        {
           "address":"0x4ed4e862860bed51a9570b96d89af5e1b0efefed",
           "blockHash":"0xbe2cadb0b88ae723bb2d87293f41c64f3242c12fe7e841f3ecc0698d6e3e9701",
           "blockNumber":"0x160cc3e",
           "data":"0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000be44b2865cd2dc95",
           "logIndex":"0xcb",
           "removed":false,
           "topics":[
              "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef",
              "0x00000000000000000000000029715d8d279cab143a12ff515b40a2b35d7bad37",
              "0x0000000000000000000000003fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad"
           ],
           "transactionHash":"0x72823453899fe671cdf0742f5dd3725d3f52e6f65660d31318e327969a850bcb",
           "transactionIndex":"0x24"
        },
        {
           "address":"0x833589fcd6edb6e08f4c7c32d4f71b54bda02913",
           "blockHash":"0xbe2cadb0b88ae723bb2d87293f41c64f3242c12fe7e841f3ecc0698d6e3e9701",
           "blockNumber":"0x160cc3e",
           "data":"0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003d340",
           "logIndex":"0xcc",
           "removed":false,
           "topics":[
              "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef",
              "0x0000000000000000000000003fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad",
              "0x00000000000000000000000029715d8d279cab143a12ff515b40a2b35d7bad37"
           ],
           "transactionHash":"0x72823453899fe671cdf0742f5dd3725d3f52e6f65660d31318e327969a850bcb",
           "transactionIndex":"0x24"
        },
        {
           "address":"0x29715d8d279cab143a12ff515b40a2b35d7bad37",
           "blockHash":"0xbe2cadb0b88ae723bb2d87293f41c64f3242c12fe7e841f3ecc0698d6e3e9701",
           "blockNumber":"0x160cc3e",
           "data":"0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff41bb4d79a32d236b000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003d340000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000241dc032d37480a0d2600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004879f8717efe6dcfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffb2be4",
           "logIndex":"0xcd",
           "removed":false,
           "topics":[
              "0xc42079f94a6350d7e6235f29174924f928cc2ac818eb64fed8004e115fbcca67",
              "0x0000000000000000000000003fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad",
              "0x0000000000000000000000003fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad"
           ],
           "transactionHash":"0x72823453899fe671cdf0742f5dd3725d3f52e6f65660d31318e327969a850bcb",
           "transactionIndex":"0x24"
        },
        {
           "address":"0x4ed4e862860bed51a9570b96d89af5e1b0efefed",
           "blockHash":"0xbe2cadb0b88ae723bb2d87293f41c64f3242c12fe7e841f3ecc0698d6e3e9701",
           "blockNumber":"0x160cc3e",
           "data":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000079c590f9d501d4",
           "logIndex":"0xce",
           "removed":false,
           "topics":[
              "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef",
              "0x0000000000000000000000003fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad",
              "0x0000000000000000000000005d64d14d2cf4fe5fe4e65b1c7e3d11e18d493091"
           ],
           "transactionHash":"0x72823453899fe671cdf0742f5dd3725d3f52e6f65660d31318e327969a850bcb",
           "transactionIndex":"0x24"
        },
        {
           "address":"0x4ed4e862860bed51a9570b96d89af5e1b0efefed",
           "blockHash":"0xbe2cadb0b88ae723bb2d87293f41c64f3242c12fe7e841f3ecc0698d6e3e9701",
           "blockNumber":"0x160cc3e",
           "data":"0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000bdcaecf562fddac1",
           "logIndex":"0xcf",
           "removed":false,
           "topics":[
              "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef",
              "0x0000000000000000000000003fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad",
              "0x000000000000000000000000f4123c2a38d9aa57801a6469b415f8116208feab"
           ],
           "transactionHash":"0x72823453899fe671cdf0742f5dd3725d3f52e6f65660d31318e327969a850bcb",
           "transactionIndex":"0x24"
        }
     ],
     "logsBloom":"0x00010000000000800000000000010000040000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000010000100020000080400014080000000000080000000800000008000000000000000000080000004000000020000000800000000000001000000000400000000844040000000000000010000800001040004000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000100000000000080000401000020000000000000000000000000000002008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000001000000000000000000002000400",
     "status":"0x1",
     "to":"0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad",
     "transactionHash":"0x72823453899fe671cdf0742f5dd3725d3f52e6f65660d31318e327969a850bcb",
     "transactionIndex":"0x24",
     "type":"0x2"
  }
}

My decoding and aggregation solution looks like this:
import { createPublicClient, http, parseAbiItem, formatUnits, getEventSelector, erc20Abi } from 'viem'
import { base, mainnet } from 'viem/chains'
import { receipt, receiptEight, receiptFive, receiptFour, receiptNine, receiptSeven, receiptSix, receiptTen, receiptThree, receiptTwo } from './receipts.js'

const baseClient = createPublicClient({
  chain: base,
  transport: http()
})

const ethereumClient = createPublicClient({
  chain: mainnet,
  transport: http()
})

// Define transfer event for filtering
const transferEvent = parseAbiItem('event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value)')
const transferEventSelector = getEventSelector(transferEvent)

// Add deposit event definition
const depositEvent = parseAbiItem('event Deposit(address indexed dst, uint256 wad)')
const depositEventSelector = getEventSelector(depositEvent)

async function decodeSwap(receipt, network = 'base') {
  const client = network === 'base' ? baseClient : ethereumClient

  const userAddress = receipt.from.toLowerCase()
  let logicPath = ''
  
  // Get all transfer and deposit logs from the receipt
  const transferLogs = receipt.logs.filter(log => 
    log.topics[0] === transferEventSelector
  )
  const depositLogs = receipt.logs.filter(log =>
    log.topics[0] === depositEventSelector
  )

  // Sort transfers by logIndex
  const sortedTransfers = transferLogs.sort((a, b) => 
    Number(a.logIndex) - Number(b.logIndex)
  )

  let sentTransfer, receivedTransfer

  // First try to find direct transfers involving the user
  for (const transfer of sortedTransfers) {
    if (transfer.topics[1].toLowerCase().includes(userAddress.slice(2))) {
      sentTransfer = transfer
      logicPath = 'Direct user transfer found'
      break
    }
  }

  // If no direct user transfer found, check for WETH deposit
  if (!sentTransfer) {
    const wethDeposit = depositLogs[0]
    if (wethDeposit) {
      sentTransfer = wethDeposit
      logicPath = 'WETH deposit found (fallback)'
    }
  }

  // Look for the received transfer after the sent transfer
  if (sentTransfer) {
    const laterTransfers = sortedTransfers.filter(t => 
      Number(t.logIndex) > Number(sentTransfer.logIndex)
    ).reverse()
    
    receivedTransfer = laterTransfers.find(t => 
      t.address.toLowerCase() !== sentTransfer.address.toLowerCase() &&
      t.topics[1].toLowerCase() !== t.topics[2].toLowerCase()
    )

    if (receivedTransfer) {
      logicPath += ' → Different token after sent transfer'
    } else {
      receivedTransfer = laterTransfers.find(t => 
        t.topics[1].toLowerCase() !== t.topics[2].toLowerCase()
      )
      if (receivedTransfer) {
        logicPath += ' → Any valid transfer after sent transfer'
      }
    }
  }

  // If we still haven't found the transfers, look for the first out and last in of different tokens
  if (!sentTransfer || !receivedTransfer) {
    sentTransfer = sortedTransfers.find(t => 
      t.topics[1].toLowerCase() !== t.topics[2].toLowerCase()
    )

    if (sentTransfer) {
      logicPath = 'First valid transfer'
      
      receivedTransfer = [...sortedTransfers].reverse().find(t => 
        t.address.toLowerCase() !== sentTransfer.address.toLowerCase() &&
        t.topics[1].toLowerCase() !== t.topics[2].toLowerCase() &&
        t !== sentTransfer
      )

      if (receivedTransfer) {
        logicPath += ' → Last different token transfer'
      } else {
        receivedTransfer = [...sortedTransfers].reverse().find(t => 
          t.topics[1].toLowerCase() !== t.topics[2].toLowerCase() &&
          t !== sentTransfer
        )
        if (receivedTransfer) {
          logicPath += ' → Last valid transfer'
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (!receivedTransfer || !sentTransfer) {
    throw new Error('Could not find swap transfers')
  }

  // Get token details
  const [sentToken, receivedToken] = await Promise.all([
    {
      address: sentTransfer.address,
      symbol: await client.readContract({
        address: sentTransfer.address,
        abi: erc20Abi,
        functionName: 'symbol'
      }),
      decimals: await client.readContract({
        address: sentTransfer.address,
        abi: erc20Abi,
        functionName: 'decimals'
      })
    },
    {
      address: receivedTransfer.address,
      symbol: await client.readContract({
        address: receivedTransfer.address,
        abi: erc20Abi,
        functionName: 'symbol'
      }),
      decimals: await client.readContract({
        address: receivedTransfer.address,
        abi: erc20Abi,
        functionName: 'decimals'
      })
    }
  ])

  // Parse the transfer amounts
  const sentAmount = formatUnits(
    BigInt(sentTransfer.data), 
    sentToken.decimals
  )
  const receivedAmount = formatUnits(
    BigInt(receivedTransfer.data),
    receivedToken.decimals
  )

  console.log('Decoded Swap Summary:')
  console.log('--------------------')
  console.log(`Logic Path: ${logicPath}`)
  console.log('\nSwap Details:')
  console.log(`Sent: ${sentAmount} ${sentToken.symbol} (${sentTransfer.address})`)
  console.log(`Received: ${receivedAmount} ${receivedToken.symbol} (${receivedTransfer.address})`)
  console.log('\n')
}

// const receiptOneMain = receipt.receipt

// const receiptTwoMain = receiptTwo.receipt



const receiptThreeMain = receiptThree.receipt
// const receiptFourMain = receiptFour.receipt

// const receiptFiveMain = receiptFive.receipt

// const receiptSixMain = receiptSix.receipt

// const receiptSevenMain = receiptSeven.receipt

// const receiptEightMain = receiptEight.receipt

// const receiptNineMain = receiptNine.receipt

// const receiptTenMain = receiptTen.receipt

// console.log("Receipt One")
// await decodeSwap(receiptOneMain, "base")
// console.log("Receipt Two")
// await decodeSwap(receiptTwoMain, "base")
console.log("Receipt Three")
await decodeSwap(receiptThreeMain, "base")
// console.log("Receipt Four")
// await decodeSwap(receiptFourMain, "base")
// console.log("Receipt Five")
// await decodeSwap(receiptFiveMain, "base")
// console.log("Receipt Six")
// await decodeSwap(receiptSixMain, "base")
// console.log("Receipt Seven")
// await decodeSwap(receiptSevenMain, "base")
// console.log("Receipt Eight")
// await decodeSwap(receiptEightMain, "base")
// console.log("Receipt Nine")
// await decodeSwap(receiptNineMain, "base")
// console.log("Receipt Ten")
// await decodeSwap(receiptTenMain, "ethereum")

Which, when ran, provides a CORRECT output like so:
Receipt Three
Decoded Swap Summary:
--------------------
Logic Path: Direct user transfer found → Different token after sent transfer

Swap Details:
Sent: 0.251056 USDT (0xfde4c96c8593536e31f229ea8f37b2ada2699bb2)
Received: 13.676003757135878849 DEGEN (0x4ed4e862860bed51a9570b96d89af5e1b0efefed)

I have tested with 9 other receipts, which are from UniSwap, 1Inch, and 3 other DEXs, and my logic here works great and seems to be correct, using different fallbacks and strategies to get the accurate in and out.
I am wondering if there are any better solutions to getting accurate swap info (that is human readable as a final result)?
Are there any flaws with my approach?
Should I use a switch-case approach based on the DEX and Version?
Please, if someone could kindly give me some pointers here that would be great.
(FYI, I already have a way to get Receipts using QuickNode Streams, so don't worry about that).

yeah use the graph instead and just query it

@johnny5 Please clarify.

instead of parsing the raw events from the RPC, you can make a simple GQL query and request it from their graph.  If you don't know what the graph is you should do some research on "thegraph" crypto it indexes block chain events so they can be queried historically, it will be much easier than parsing the events from the RPC

Unfortunately there are no standards for DEXes, or their events.

You need to integrate and decode each DEX type individually

